# Mid-90s cartoon: team of heroes in summonable, mechanized power armors, one is a werewolf

Tags: story-identification, tv, cartoon

It was about a team of heroes, all of which had some sort of mechanized power armor they could conceal and summon at will. I think they were young adults. Not exactly kids, not grown up, late teens maybe. One member of the team didn't have the armor but would instead turn into a werewolf. They had some sort of flying craft that they used to travel together.

I especially vividly remember an episode where the werewolf guy, while in his human form, was being seduced by what looked like a pair of attractive women who promptly revealed themselves to be some kind of alien monsters ready to eat him, only for him to turn into the werewolf and kick their asses instead.

Edit: Found the specific scenario and it's a little different than I remember but still that has to be it:

Comment: Out of curiosity - why remove the episode you remembered? It could help others looking for the same cartoon :)

Comment: I'll leave it! Changed my mind.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This appears to be [*Monster Force*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monster_Force), which ran for 13 episodes in 1994.  Most of them are equipped with powered armour created by their leader:

> Dr. Reed Crawley alias Doc (voiced by Lawrence Bayne)
>
> A young yet brilliant scientist who is also the main tactician and
> strategist of the team. He has once been Dracula's captive and since
> then vowed to end his reign of terror. Apparently, he is the inventor
> of the entire cutting-edge weaponry and equipment used by Monster
> Force. One of his most brilliant inventions is the EMACS (Energized
> Monster Armed Containment Suit) or simply power suit, which allows
> normal humans to fight super-human dark powers at the same level.

and they do indeed have a werewolf on the team:

> Luke Talbot alias the Wolfman (voiced by Paul Haddad)
>
> The only werewolf in the team and the only one (apart from
> Frankenstein) who doesn't utilize high tech devices invented by Doc.
> He is actually a good-natured young man affected by lycanthropy, which
> has been the curse of his family for generations. During the full
> moon, when he cannot control the curse, his teammates have to restrain
> him but otherwise his Wolfman form makes him nearly invincible in a
> monster-to-monster fight.
>
> He's apparently descended from Lawrence Talbot, the original wolfman.

The first seven episodes were released on DVD in 2009, and some of them are currently on YouTube.  I can't find the specific scenario you're referring to, though.

### Opening Credits

Comment: That's it! Thank you so much!

Comment: EMACS ?????????